# RoR active record association querying with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, conditional-statements

What I am trying to do is the following:
Say we have a post that may have many questions and answers where both questions and answers belong to a given post. What I am trying to figure out is how to get the posts that have less than 5 questions and answers together.

something like:

```
@posts = Post.where(post.questions + post.answers < 5)
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new field on the table that would hold the sum of the questions and answers of a post. This could be done using a callback like this:

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...

    # After you've created the sum field (migration etc.)
    before_save do |post|
      post.sum = post.questions.count + post.answers.count
    end
  end
```

Then in your controller you could do `@posts = Post.where('sum < 5')`

Comment: And what happens when the answers or the questions change?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Squeel:
http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/

Allows traversing associations, among many other things, in your query.